# OWSTimer.exe suddenly disappeared

Tags: 2007, development, timer-jobs, wspbuilder

I am testing/debugging this Timer Job, while deploying my solution again and again using WSP Builder, I manage to hide OWSTimer.exe so now I cant find it to attach timer job to and debug my code, anyone got any clue ?

**Edit**

Restarting my VPC solved the issue

Comment: Why and how would you hide OWSTimer.exe?

Comment: I didn't it just happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart the SharePoint timer service!

Comment: Sorry but how I will be able to do that :S

Comment: I find it, it named as "Windows SharePoint Timer Service"

Answer (score 5):

Ok, first are both checkboxes at the bottom marked ("Show processes from all users" and "Show processes in all sessions")? If so, maybe you changed the type of code shown under the "Attach to:" field. I would dig through these three settings.

[image: Attach To Process]

If you still can't find the process after that, try an old fashioned reboot.

Answer (score 2):

"Have you tried turning it off and on yet?" =)